# Subsetting a dataframe with dplyr by first a categorial variable and the classwise frequency of a given value range within a second variable

Tags: r, class, dplyr

In my project I want to subset a dataframe with using dplyr by keeping only the rows of say variable1-class that has the most entries witinh a given value range in variable2. 
As this may sound quite ambiguous here, but my dataframe is quite big I'll give you an example by the *mtcars* dataframe.

At the image below you see the dataframe sorted by the variable *carb*.
Now, I want (if possible with `dplyr`),

1. to filter out the TWO *carb*-classes, that have the most according *drat*-values between 4.0 and 4.3.
2. From the two winner-classes not all rows should be kept, but only the rows within the mentionned *drat*-range from 4.0 to 4.3.
   And subsequently:
3. If the second place should be shared by two or more *carb*-classes (as in the example), or the first place should be shared by three or more *carb*-classes, the 'winning' classes should specified by random (if possible repeatable random, analogous to `set.seed`)

In the end, the subset should just consist either of the 4 red marked or the 4 blue marked rows (three rows out of *carb*-class 1 'as winner' and one row from one of the classes 2 or 4, respectively, according to random)

I do have a basic understanding of subsetting with using dplyr. But my problem in this case is to check/compare values which have to be derived from whole, classwise 'sub-entities', - as a filtering-condition.

May anybody help here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to use the `rank()` function, which has an option to settle ties randomly.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(415)

# subset drat
mt_drat <- mtcars %>%
  filter(between(drat, 4, 4.3)) 

# rank by number of rows, randomly decide ties
mt_rank <- mt_drat %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(-n, ties.method = 'random')) %>%
  filter(rank %in% 1:2)
  
# filter to winners
mt_drat %>%
  filter(carb %in% mt_rank$carb)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>